# How to check if an array of strings contains a value in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, kotlin

How can I check if an array of strings contains a value in Kotlin? Just like ruby's `#include?`.

I thought about:

```kotlin
array.filter { it == "value" }.any()
```

Is there another way?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

The equivalent you are looking for is the [contains](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/contains.html) operator.

```
array.contains("value")
```

Kotlin offer an alternative [infix notation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#infix-notation) for this operator:

```
"value" in array
```

It's the same function called behind the scene, but since [infix notation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#infix-notation) isn't found in Java we could say that `in` is the most idiomatic way.

Comment: When I try this in Kotlin I get a "Type inference failed. The value of the type parameter T should be mentioned in the input Types."

 private var domainsArray = arrayOf("@ebay.com", "@google.com", "@gmail.com", "@umd.edu")


var domainFound = Arrays.asList(domainsArray).contains(email)

Comment: Just write var domainFound = domainsArray.contains(email) or more idiomatic var domainFound = email in domainsArray

Comment: Any idea how to compare with ignorecase string? array.contains("value")  do not check ignorecase for string.

Comment: You could map array with the toLowerCase String extension function before calling contains.

Answer (score 137):

You could also check if the array contains an object with some specific field to compare with using `any()`

```
listOfObjects.any{ object -> object.fieldxyz == value_to_compare_here }
```

Answer (score 45):

Here is code where you can find specific field in ArrayList with objects. The answer of Amar Jain helped me:

```
listOfObjects.any{ it.field == "value"}
```

Answer (score 39):

Using **in** operator is an idiomatic way to do that.

```
val contains = "a" in arrayOf("a", "b", "c")
```

Answer (score 24):

You can use the [`in` operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#inOperation) which, in this case, calls [`contains`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/contains.html):

`"value" in array`

Answer (score 10):

You can use it..contains(" ")

```
 data class Animal (val name:String)


 val animals = listOf(Animal("Lion"), Animal("Elephant"), Animal("Tiger"))

 println(animals.filter { it.name.contains("n") }.toString())
```

output will be

```
[Animal(name=Lion), Animal(name=Elephant)]
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `find` method, that returns the first element matching the given [predicate], or `null` if no such element was found.
Try this code to find `value` in `array` of objects

```
 val findedElement = array?.find {
            it.id == value.id
 }
 if (findedElement != null) {
 //your code here           
 }
```

Comment: How can you get the position of findedElement value from array?

Comment: @AnzyShQ you can find a position with a methods `array.indexIf(Object o)` -> will return you index of first founded element, `array.lastIndexOf(Object o)` -> will return you index of last founded element. You can also use predicate too, etc `array.indexOfLast { it.name == "test " }` or `array.indexOfFirst { it.name == "test "}`