# Kotlin: using .contains() for nested attributes

Tags: kotlin

is it possible to use .contains() method in order to check for object with the same id without assigning mentionedTasks ...

```
 ... arrayListOf<OrderSmallDTO> to arrayListOf<int>?


        private var mentionedTasks = arrayListOf<OrderSmallDTO>()

        composite.add(repository.getOrders(params)
                .subscribe({orders ->
                    orders.tasksList.forEach { order ->
                        if (!mentionedTasks.contains(order.id)) {
                            mentionedTasks.add(order)
                        }
                    }
                    checkForDelay()
                }, {}))
```

OrderSmallDTO contains id fieds as well as many others

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42234775/kotlin-idiomatic-way-to-check-array-contains-value

Comment: it does not work since mentionedTasks is not an array of int but of objects that contain this field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 1

use `!in` for a mapped collection of ids

```
if (order.id !in mentionedTasks.map{ it.id }) {
   mentionedTasks.add(order)
}
```

### Solution 2

use contains for a mapped collection of ids

```
if (!mentionedTasks.map{ it.id }.contains(order.id)) {
   mentionedTasks.add(order)
}
```

### Solution 3

Override `equals` and `hashCode` for `OrderSmallDTO` to check for id field, to achieve this:

```
if (mentionedTasks.contains(order)) {
   mentionedTasks.add(order)
}
```

Comment: While all proposed solutions solve the initial question, I strongly suggest the use of a map or set vs the use of a List due to performance.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your question correctly. What do you mean by "without assigning mentionedTasks"?

Regardless I believe this solves your problem:

```
    private var mentionedTasks = arrayListOf<OrderSmallDTO>()

    composite.add(repository.getOrders(params)
            .subscribe({orders ->
                orders.tasksList.distinctBy(OrderSmallDTO::id).forEach { order ->
                    mentionedTasks.add(order)
                }
                checkForDelay()
            }, {}))
```

If the mentionedTasks are not modified afterwards, I suggest you use an immutable List like this:

```
    private var mentionedTasks = emptyList<OrderSmallDTO>()

    composite.add(repository.getOrders(params)
            .subscribe({orders ->
                mentionedTasks = orders.tasksList.distinctBy(OrderSmallDTO::id)
                checkForDelay()
            }, {}))
```

If you do want to add additional tasks to the List later on, then List is not an appropriate type. You should instead use a Map. See an example below. Note that I am assuming `order.id` is of type `Int`.

```
    private var mentionedTasks = mutableMapOf<Int, OrderSmallDTO>()

    composite.add(repository.getOrders(params)
            .subscribe({orders ->
                mentionedTasks.putAll(orders.tasksList.map {Pair(it.id, it)})
                checkForDelay()
            }, {}))
```

And if you need the mentionedTasks as a List you can invoke `mentionedTasksById.values.asList()`.

Comment: it work, but only for single call where mentionedTasks are being update continuously and i need to ensure to not have two fields with the same id throughout all calls

Comment: by assigning mentionedTasks to a new array i ment to extract id fields from all mentioned Tasks and assign them to a new array that holds integers